# Firebase QueryOrderedByChild along with EqualToValue and StartingAtValue Combination

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to query Firebase by a Child that is equal to a certain value BUT start the snapshot at a specific post key.

**Data Structure:**

```
projectName
  -posts
    -postKey1
      -storeId: 1
    -postKey2
       -storeId: 2
    -postKey3
       -storeId:3
    -postKey4
       -storeId:2
    -postKey5
       -storeId:3
    -postKey6
       -storeId:2
```

**Example:**

I am trying to `queryOrderedByChild("storeId")` with `queryEqualToValue("2")` BUT I would like the snapshot to start at "postKey4" when it is returned in its order.

**My Current Query:**

```
ref.queryOrderedByChild("storeId").queryEqualToValue("\(myId)").observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: {snapshot in
```

I know that you can't call `queryEqualToValue:` after `queryStartingAtValue`, `queryEndingAtValue` or `queryEqualToValue` after previously called but I need that `queryEqualToValue` to get my storeId. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

You can pass a second argument into `queryStartingAtValue` that specifies the key at which to start.

```
ref.queryOrderedByChild("storeId")
   .queryStartingAtValue(2, childKey: "postKey4")
   .queryEndingAtValue(2)
   .observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: {snapshot in
       for childSnapshot in snapshot.children {
           print(childSnapshot.key!!
       }
})
```

This prints:

> postKey4
>
> postKey6

I must admit this is the first time I use the second argument to `queryStartingAtValue`, so I might not understand it completely yet.

The reason you can't use `queryEqualToValue` is that that will only return a single key, which is not what you want.