# How to get firebase data by date range and some other parameter at the same time

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to write query to firebase that get posts by `posterId` and for specified date range.
`Dates` are stored as `number`.

```
reference.child("posts")
                .queryOrderedByChild(posterId)
                .queryStartingAtValue(1483706035, childKey: "postedOnDate")
                .queryEndingAtValue(1483707046)
                .queryEqualToValue("-KasdASDHGASasdsa986")
                .observeEventType(...
```

I am getting error:

```
'InvalidQueryParameter', reason: 'Can't call queryEqualToValue: after queryStartingAtValue, queryEndingAtValue or queryEqualToValue was previously called'
```

If I remove `queryEqualToValue` I don't get error but I don't get data neither.
What I did wrong in my query, or what I am missing in this query?
It's simple query don't know why it doesn't work.

Comment: Firebase Database queries can only order/filter on one property/key at a time. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26700924/query-based-on-multiple-where-clauses-in-firebase. The `childKey:` parameter does not allow you to pass in a second property name, but is instead used in pagination scenarios. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41065931/filtered-paginated-list-with-firebase and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38933148/firebase-queryorderedbychild-along-with-equaltovalue-and-startingatvalue-combina/38934094#38934094

Answer (score 0):

please try this code,it helps you

```
ref.child("posts")
            .queryOrderedByChild(posterId)
            .queryStartingAtValue("Range1")
            .queryEndingAtValue("Range2")
                   .observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in
                    print(snapshot.key)
                })
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I am creating a date data, uploading it to firebase, retrieving and then finally, sorting it. All done based on the nearest date in my chat *JSON* tree

This is the end result for retrieving keys from my firebase database based on the nearest date

---

[image]

---

First declare a constant called timestamp

```
 let timestamp = NSNumber(value: Int(Date().timeIntervalSince1970))
```

Synchronized it with the other values in your DB, and push it to firebase

[image]

finally, the comparison method

```
    // DISPAY AND SORT TIMER BETWEEN CHAT MESSAGES BASED ON TIMESTAMP
    self.messages.sort(by: { (message1, message2) -> Bool in

        (message1.timestamp.intValue)! > (message2.timestamp?.intValue)!

    })
```